# 2 variables pointing the same address in memory name

Tags: computer-science

What is the name of the situation where 2 variables pointing the same location in memory, and any change in one of them, will change the other?

example:

```
String a = "1";
String b = a;
b = "3";
print(a); // will print "3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you're looking for is [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29) .

Answer (score 0):

You mean C-style pointers?

```
int * a = 42;
int * b;
b = a;
*b++;
printf('%d', *a); // prints 43
```

Since they'd be pointing at the **SAME** location in memory, using one of the pointers to change what's at that memory location by definition also changes what the other pointer is pointing at, since the location is the SAME.

Comment: im looking for the name/word/term - not the description. tnx!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting b **by reference**.